# channel message statistics with get_stats

Tags: telethon

I'am trying to get message statistics using telethon get_stats.

```
channel = '@test'
async with client:
    stats = await client.get_stats(entity=channel,message=92)
    print(stats.stringify())
```

But I keep getting `ChatAdminRequiredError`

Can it be used only for channels where I am admin?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.get_stats):

> Note that some restrictions apply before being able to fetch statistics, in particular the channel must have enough members (for megagroups, this requires at least 500 members).

and

> If there are not enough members (poorly named) errors such as `telethon.errors.ChatAdminRequiredError` will appear.